# Is there a way to "pre-load" Awesomebar with all my Google Docs?

Tags: firefox, google-docs, awesomebar

It's convenient to just type the title of a Google Doc and see it pop up in the Awesomebar, but it only works for docs I've opened in the last month or so.  Is there a way to pre-load all the doc titles into awesomebar permanently, or have them show up as bookmarks the way delicious bookmarks show up?  An extension or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you bookmark all of your Docs, they will show up in the awesome bar. You may also want to try [gDocsBar](http://www.gdocsbar.com/), a Firefox extension which allows you to drag and drop multiple files into the sidebar to upload documents. You can even search and filter documents from the sidebar itself:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I have hundreds of docs, and the number is increasing all the time.  I want something that adds them to the bookmarks automatically or syncs my bookmarks with the list of docs or something.